# How to create a hyper link that opens in Google Maps for Android devices or Apple maps for iOS devices?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, apple-maps

I'd like to use media queries (or any other means) in my website to detect the user agent and display a link that will open in Apple Maps if the user is on an iOS device or in Google Maps if the user is on an Android device.

The only other related question I can find is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13924829/how-to-open-links-in-apple-maps-or-google-maps) and it's quite old.

Comment: Duplicate of [How to launch Google Maps on iPhone via web link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18223533/how-to-launch-google-maps-on-iphone-via-web-link)

Comment: @MrUpsidown The linked question in no way addresses what I've asked here. I'm asking how I can detect the user agent and provide one html element that will open the native map application on a mobile device.

Answer (score 1):

To launch google maps on android, or if installed on IOS, launch this URL:

`https://www.google.com/maps/`

[Google maps URLs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/get-started)

To launch apple maps on IOS devices, launch this URL:

`http://maps.apple.com`

[Apple maps Map links](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html)

**Both links will open in the browser if the app is not installed/disabled.**